# Partial functionality of .animate() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the div on the right to push itself away from the one on  the left on `mouseenter` and return to its position on `mouseleave`. The changing background colors confirm the event listener works. Why does

```
$( this ).animate(function() {
  left: "+=10px";
  top: "+=10px"
})
```

not do anything?

Here is a link to the codepen

http://codepen.io/WallyNally/pen/RRzBAb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the page for [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  You should be passing a plain object instead of a function to it.  The thing that you are animating also cannot have a CSS position of static.  In the fiddle below I've made the position relative, but you could also do absolute or fixed.

[Fiddle w/ solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tburki/onxuosj1/)

```
$('#myDiv').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: "+=10px",
    top: "+=10px"
  });
});

$('#myDiv').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    left: '-=10px',
    top: '-=10px'
  });
})
```

Comment: thanks! What's the benefit of using `.on('mouseenter')` over a direct `.mouseenter()`?

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of using .on for the sole purpose that it [supports delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), but there is nothing wrong with using .mouseenter() as it's just shorthand for .on('mouseenter').